# HackerRank frequency Queries(Java)

Tags: java, hashmap

This is HackerRanks frequency queries problem and I don't know why it fails 4 test cases, specifically cases 8,9,11 and 12.  I have provided my code below along with comments for my logic. If someone could explain the flaw in my logic to pass all the test cases that would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the link to the problem
[Frequency Querie problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/frequency-queries/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dictionaries-hashmaps)

```
static List<Integer> freqQuery(List<List<Integer>> queries) {
    //key stores the inserted data value
    //value stores the occurence/count of each value
    HashMap <Integer,Integer> hm = new HashMap();
    ArrayList<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++){
        //[(1,1),(2,2),(3,2),(1,1)]
        //rule is idx 0 in each array, value/key is idx 1 in each array
        int key = queries.get(i).get(1);
        int rule = queries.get(i).get(0);
        //rule add to hashmap 
        if(rule == 1){
            //[1,x], stores x into the hashmap if exists and increments frequency 
            if(hm.containsKey(key)){
                hm.put(key, hm.get(key) + 1);
            }
            //otherwise add to hashmap with frequency of 1 
            else{
                hm.put(key, 1 );
            }
        }
        else if(rule == 2){
            //[2,y], remove y from hashmap if exists
            if(hm.containsKey(key)){
                hm.put(key, hm.get(key) - 1);
            }
        }
        else{
            //[3,z], if z in hashmap add 1 to answer arraylist 
            //if hm contains, add 1 to arraylist
            if(hm.containsValue(key)){
                answer.add(1);
            }
            else{
                answer.add(0);
            }
        }
       
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the input that is used for these test cases and what the required result is?

Comment: The input it fails are for very large test cases of 10,000+ values. For some reason these specific test cases of 10,000+ values are failed while other test cases with 10,000+ values are passed. This is why I am confused as I cant see exactly where it fails and why my output is wrong due to the large sample size.

Comment: You allow the count for a key to go negative. Cases 10 and 11 won't pass when rule 3 is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

```
static List<Integer> freqQuery(List<List<Integer>> queries) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
    int[] quantities = new int[queries.size() + 1];
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int frequency, value;
    for (List<Integer> query : queries) {
        value = query.get(1);
        switch (query.get(0)) {
        case 1:
            frequency = frequencies.getOrDefault(value, 0);
            frequencies.put(value, frequency + 1);
            quantities[frequency]--;
            quantities[frequency + 1]++;
            break;
        case 2:
            frequency = frequencies.getOrDefault(value, 0);
            if (frequency == 0)
                break;
            if (frequency == 1)
                frequencies.remove(value);
            else
                frequencies.put(value, frequency - 1);
            // process qt
            quantities[frequency]--;
            quantities[frequency - 1]++;
            break;
        case 3:
            if (value >= quantities.length)
                result.add(0);
            else
                result.add(quantities[value] > 0 ? 1 : 0);
            break;

        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].